# iOS GIDSignIn require type password every time

Tags: ios, google-signin

After calling `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut]`, users require to type username and password again when they tap the sign-in button. Is it possible to change this behaviour? I want user to select account that has logged in before instead of typing username and password every time. Many thanks.

Comment: I think the account is already their even after logout but ask you too enter password.

Comment: I tried the sample app from Google. I have to type my Google ID and password again after tapping the sign in button

Comment: Its the shared instance of webpage on webview. And their is account available even after signout on web.